# Securing REST API with @PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_NEW')) annotations where role is extracted from KeyCloak JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, keycloak

My goal is to secure REST API endpoint in Spring Boot app using `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_NEW'))` annotation.
Role has to be extracted from JWT supplied by KeyCloak.

RestController is below. The project is the same as [SpringBoot REST Service Protected Using Keycloak Authorization Services](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-springboot).

```
@RestController
public class ApplicationController {

    @PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_NEW'))
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/resourceannotated", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String handleResourceAnnotated() {
        return createResponse();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/resourcea", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleResourceA() {
        return createResponse();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/resourceb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleResourceB() {
        return createResponse();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/premium", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handlePremiumResource() {
        return createResponse();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleAdminResource() {
        return createResponse();
    }

    private String createResponse() {
        return "Access Granted";
    }
```

User *test* with role *NEW* was added to *KeyCloak* and I expected requests sent with *JWTs* to */api/resourceannotated* endpoint to be authorized only for users with role *NEW* which will be extracted from *JWT*.

The motivation is saving request to *KeyCloak* which enforces access control to 
*/api/resourcea, /api/resourceb, /api/premium, /api/admin* endpoints using policy enforcers.

How to do it correctly? 
Tried [Using JWT's with Spring Security's @PreAuthorize annotation for method specific security](https://softeng.oicr.on.ca/alex_lepsa/2018/03/22/Spring-Method-Security-Using-JWTs/) and [USE KEYCLOAK WITH YOUR SPRING BOOT 2 APPLICATION](https://info.michael-simons.eu/2017/12/28/use-keycloak-with-your-spring-boot-2-application/) without success. I get the below error:

> {
>       "timestamp": "2018-08-30T14:37:39.409+0000",
>       "status": 401,
>       "error": "Unauthorized",
>       "message": "Unauthorized",
>       "path": "/api/resourceannotated" }

When run in debug mode 2 messages are printed:

> 2018-08-30 17:55:47.586 DEBUG 31006 --- [nio-8180-exec-3]
>   o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to
>   thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@62b92856
>   2018-08-30 17:55:47.592 DEBUG 31006 --- [nio-8180-exec-3]
>   o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound
>   request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@62b92856

Enabled debug logging for *org.springframework.security*

and getting the below errors:

```
DEBUG 30677 --- [           main] s.s.c.a.w.c.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter : Using default configure(HttpSecurity). If subclassed this will potentially override subclass configure(HttpSecurity).
 DEBUG 30677 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1
 DEBUG 30677 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
 DEBUG 30677 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
  INFO 30677 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@31c2affc, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@f72203, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2d2acd89, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6e1d4137, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@149f5761, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1237e0be, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@2ab2710, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@6441c486, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@540dbda9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@27b000f7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1dc2de84, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e6dad8, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2d5f7182, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@58a4a74d]
  INFO 30677 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
  INFO 30677 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8180 (http) with context path ''
  INFO 30677 --- [           main] o.k.quickstart.springboot.MyApplication  : Started MyApplication in 14.439 seconds (JVM running for 17.843)
  INFO 30677 --- [] o.k.a.authorization.PolicyEnforcer       : Paths provided in configuration.
  INFO 30677 --- [] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
  INFO 30677 --- [] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
  INFO 30677 --- [] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 73 ms
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/resourceannotated' doesn't match 'POST /logout
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/resourceannotated' doesn't match 'POST /login
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@c551e2ad: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de6: RemoteIpAddress: 10.88.0.23; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID A64F605948A7B529457A226B238A5EEC is invalid.
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/resourceannotated at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/resourceannotated; Attributes: [authenticated]
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@c551e2ad: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de6: RemoteIpAddress: 10.88.0.23; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@14cd10fa, returned: -1
 DEBUG 30677 --- [] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Comment: A role named NEW isn’t the same as ROLE_NEW. Hence your rule won’t match.

Comment: even if changed to NEW, i get unauthorized error. i append ROLE_ because [Expression-Based Access Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html) says to do so

Comment: That stil won’t match. You are geting NEW from keycloak but are verifying it with ROLE_NEW. Instead of hasRole use hasAuthority.

Comment: changed to NEW, using hasAuthority. still getting the same error.

Comment: Is the token actually being send? Enable debug logging to see what is going on.

Comment: ran with debug mode, attached 2 messages which pop when the request with JWT is sent

Comment: Apparently you want trace logging then or expliclity enable debug/trace logging for `org.springframework.security` instead.

Comment: Did you change the `application.properties` file to reflect the new role and endpoint? Looking at the properties from the github repo you linked, the new endpoint would also require the role `user`. 
Also I think that in order to use `@PreAuthorize` you also need `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` in your config class.

Comment: @M. Deinum enabled debug mode for `org.springframework.security` and see access denied errors

Comment: 401 means you aren’t authenticated. Of you see the debug info nothing is happening with the token, in the end you are an anonymous user. There is no JWT filter or keycloak stuff in the whole flow. Hence that isn’t configured correctly.

Comment: Which keycloak adapter do you have configured in the application?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker didn't configure. just used the pom file from github